# Add an onClick to an Infragistics WebDataGrid

Tags: c#, infragistics, webdatagrid

I have an Infragistics WebDataGrid and I want to fire a server side event every time a cell is clicked on. I know that I can make a button and add an onclick to that, but I want some or all the data cells to be clickable.
I also saw this(https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ultimate-ui-for-asp-net/108226/onclick-event-for-webdatagrid) but I need the event to fire server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

1. Handle ["Click"](https://www.infragistics.com/help/aspnet/infragistics.web~infragistics.web.ui.gridcontrols.gridclientevents~click) client event and call [__doPostBack](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function.all) js function to trigger a postback. Page_Load server event will help you to determine whether the postback is caused by the click or not. Things to consider, client event ["Click"](https://www.infragistics.com/help/aspnet/infragistics.web~infragistics.web.ui.gridcontrols.gridclientevents~click) will be fired on every click inside the Grid, have a look at the provided [API link](https://www.infragistics.com/help/aspnet/infragistics.web~infragistics.web.ui.gridcontrols.gridclientevents~click) for more info.
2. Activate Selection behavior, and handle CellSelectionChanged client event. From here use the approach with [__doPostBack](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function.all).

The Grid is very powerful control with a rich API and the behaviors, so we could thing of a different way to achieve this.

Snippet:

```
..
<script>
        function client_click(sender, evtArgs) {
            // First Approach
            __doPostBack('myRequest', "someValue");
        }

        function WDG_Selection_CellSelectionChanged(sender, eventArgs)
        {
            // Second Approach
            __doPostBack('myRequest', "someValue");
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <ig:WebDataGrid runat="server" ID="WDG" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="600px">
            <ClientEvents Click="client_click" />
            <Columns>
                <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="CategoryId" Key="CategoryId">
                    <Header Text="CategoryId">
                    </Header>
                </ig:BoundDataField>
                <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="CategoryName" Key="CategoryName">
                    <Header Text="CategoryName">
                    </Header>
                </ig:BoundDataField>
                <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="Description" Key="Description">
                    <Header Text="Description">
                    </Header>
                </ig:BoundDataField>
            </Columns>
            <Behaviors>
                <ig:EditingCore>
                    <Behaviors>
                        <ig:CellEditing>
                            <CellEditingClientEvents EnteringEditMode="entering_edit_mode" />
                        </ig:CellEditing>
                    </Behaviors>
                </ig:EditingCore>
                <ig:Selection>
                    <SelectionClientEvents CellSelectionChanged="WDG_Selection_CellSelectionChanged" />
                </ig:Selection>
            </Behaviors>
        </ig:WebDataGrid>


..
```

c#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
```

...

Comment: And evtArgs/eventArgs will let me figure out which cell was clicked?

Comment: Exactly! 

"evtArgs.get_item()" will give you the Cell element:
"$IG.GridCell {_row: $IG.GridRow, _flags: null, _props: Array(0), _element: td, _owner: $IG.WebDataGrid, …}"

"evtArgs.get_type()" will give you the clicked item type
"cell"